# Sumar valores a un diccionario python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, diccionarios

Hola ¿Cómo están? Estoy en problemas. Tengo un Txt llamado Pruba.txt

```
{'@hernesto': ['alto', '232']}
{'@juanita': ['bajo', '123']}
{'@pedro': ['mediano', 'rojo']}
{'@juanita': ['rojo', 'azul']}
{'@pedro': ['violeta', 'marron']}
{'@hernesto': ['verde', 'amarillo']}
{'@hernesto': []}
```

Como puede ver en el txt, las keys se repiten, mi idea es leerlas como un diccionario y al mismo tiempo agregar las que se repiten.
tiene que quedar de la siguiente manera

```
{'@hernesto': ['alto', '232','verde', 'amarillo']}
{'@juanita': ['bajo', '123','rojo','azul']}
{'@pedro': ['mediano', 'rojo','violeta', 'marron']}
```

se le suma los valores a la key correspondiente:

```
mi_dict = {}
with open("Pruba.txt", "r") as fp:
    for linea in fp.readlines():
        mi_dict.update(eval(linea))
print(mi_dict)
```

ese es el codigo que hice ... pero lo unico que hace es que me toma la ultima linea para cada key y no se la suma a las demas.
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar, cuando haces `mi_dict.update(eval(linea))`, estás **reemplazando** la clave anterior (por ejemplo '@pedro') con la nueva clave encontrada en el archivo. Como son `list`s, el método `lista.extend()` te sirve, lo que hace es juntar dos listas, por ejemplo:

```
ls = [1, 2, 3]
ls2 = [4, 5]
ls.extend(ls2)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

hice un par de cambios para que sea más simple de leer...

```
dict_linea = eval(linea.strip()) # Crea el diccionario en base a la línea
clave_texto = list(dict_linea.keys())[0] # es la clave de la línea actual, como str()
```

Ahora entonces, ya viste cómo usar el `extend` ¿cómo añadir las claves "nuevas" a mi diccionario? simplemente con un `try .. except`. Intento extender la lista de la clave que estamos evaluando, pero si da error... Es porque la clave no existe aún en el diccionario! Y como no existe, entonces mejor la declaro:

```
try:
    mi_dict[clave_texto].extend(dict_linea[clave_texto])
except KeyError:
    mi_dict[clave_texto] = dict_linea[clave_texto]
```

Adicionalmente, usar `eval(arg)` es considerado inseguro. mejor usemos `ast.literal_eval(arg)` de esta forma:

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(linea)
```

Finalmente, acomodando todo al código original, tenemos
import ast

```
mi_dict = {}
with open("Pruba.txt", "r") as fp:
    for linea in fp.readlines():
        dict_linea = ast.literal_eval(linea.strip())
        clave_texto = list(dict_linea.keys())[0]
        try:
            mi_dict[clave_texto].extend(dict_linea[clave_texto])
        except KeyError:
            mi_dict[clave_texto] = dict_linea[clave_texto]
```

Comment: Danny una genial ! ademas muy bien explicado , la verdad estuve a full con la pc y nunca se me ocurrió lo del try and except . Muy buen aporte a la comunidad

Comment: Viendo la otra respuesta, me hizo recordar que `eval` es bastante peligroso y deberías usar `ast.literal_eval(line)`, luego de hacer un `import ast`

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
import json
with open("Pruba.txt", "r") as fp:
for linea in fp.readlines():  
  data = json.loads(linea)
  for key, val in zip(data.keys(), data.values()):
    if not key in mi_dict:
      mi_dict.update(data)
    else:
      mi_dict[key].extend(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

¿no probó con simplejson? como dijo Rodrigo, salvando el archivo como 'pruba.json' el código sería el siguiente:

```
import simplejson as json
with open('pruba.json') as file:
    json.load(file)
```

Pero como el archivo contiene comillas simples y no tiene comas no es un json, para eso debería cambiarse tal que así:

```
import json
mi_dict = {}
with open("pruba.txt", "r") as fp:
    for linea in fp.readlines():
        linea = linea.replace("'", "\"")
        data = json.loads(linea)
        for key, val in zip(data.keys(), data.values()):
            if not key in mi_dict:
                mi_dict.update(data)
            else:
                mi_dict[key].extend(val)
    fp.close()
print mi_dict
```